# Run a command in mongodb container with credentials from outside

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to set the compatibility version in mongodb, which is running in a container, but from outside:

```
docker exec -it docker-compose_mongodb_1 bash -c 'mongo -uroot -p rootpassword --eval "db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.0" } )"'



MongoDB shell version v4.0.23
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("7945d913-f77c-4242-be33-af8e20c07374") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.23
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Command argument must be of type String, but was of type double in: { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: 4.0, lsid: { id: UUID(\"7945d913-f77c-4242-be33-af8e20c07374\") }, $db: \"admin\" }. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-feature-compatibility.",
        "code" : 14,
        "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a quoting problem: you seem to have double quotes around `"4.0"`, but you've already quoted the entire argument to the `--eval` argument, so the effect of these quotes isn't what you want (the value (`4.0`) ends up unquoted, hence the error ("argument must be of type String, but was of type double").

In theory you can just escape the inner quotes:

```
docker exec -it docker-compose_mongodb_1 bash -c 'mongo -uroot -p rootpassword --eval "db.adminCommand( {setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"4.0\" } )"'
```